# What's the use of Database caching?

Tags: database, codeigniter, caching

I'm seeing there is a library for caching database queries in Code Igniter.

What's the point of it? I feel like it's a stupid concept since accessing data on drive is heavier than accessing it on a database.

Comment: Imagine if you have 800 machines accessing the same database for data that almost never changes. Caching can significantly reduce the load on the database.

Answer (score 4):

Database cacheing typically occurs in memory, not on disk.  Frequent requests are returned immediately from memory when a subsequent request of the same type is made.  This is perfect for repeatable queries like menus and other navigational requests.

Comment: Is database caching helpful for the queries like this `SELECT * FROM servers s WHERE s.added_date BETWEEN 'y/m/d' AND 'y/m/d'` where date values are changeable.

Comment: @code Protocol I'd say it depends on the frequency of the call.